# CMake installation issue on raspbian stretch

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

im having some troubles installing CMake on raspberry pi 3 running raspbian stretch.

I keep getting this error message when i run the command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config
```

The error message:

```
> " Reading package lists... Done  Building dependency tree Reading
> state information... Done  Package CMake is not available, but is
> referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is
> missing, has been obsoleted, or  is only available from another source
> 
> E: Package 'cmake' has no installation candidate "
```

I've tried other installation methods like "`pip install cmake`" & "`sudo apt-get install -y cmake`" but all to no avail. Could you guys help me out? Is there a library i can extract from?

Thank you in advance.

Im running raspbian stretch 2018-03-13 installed on raspberry pi 3.

Comment: What's in Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ? Is it `stretch lite` or just `stretch`? Also, have You executed `apt-get update` first?

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config
```